# Grafana Explore filtering on Parsed Field

Tags: grafana

I have a basic Grafana parsed log where I have a query to view all the logs in Production:

```
{environment="production"}
```

Is there a way to filter on *Parsed Fields* that are not labels in these queries? For example, my parsed query looks like:

[image: parsed Log information]

Is it possible to filter on *host*, *level* or *name* without having them as labels?

Comment: if it's still valid, could you please attach the log lines and I will provide a query

Answer (score 2):

You can do use JSON parsing / LogQL as follows:

```
{environment="production"}|json|level="debug"
```

also see related [Grafana Community post](https://community.grafana.com/t/questions-about-loki-logql-and-json-parsed-fields/38811).